# Prove that you can remove one of $2022$ natural numbers so that the product of the remaining $2021$ numbers can be written as $a^2-b^2$....

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Prove that you can remove one of $2022$ natural numbers so that the product of the remaining $2021$ numbers can be written as $a^2-b^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers.

This problem was featured in a contest in my country recently. There were no solutions released and I'm not sure how to start this problem. Any help is appreciated, including hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know which natural numbers can be written in that form?

Comment: @J.G. This is the whole statement, this is why I was so puzzled by the problem

Comment: No, I mean do you know which natural numbers are of the form $a^2-b^2$ with $a,\,b$ natural? It's a hint.

Comment: @J.G. Are you inferring to $(a-b)(a+b)$?

Comment: Actually, no, so I'll make this hint more specific. Show any natural not of the form $4k+2$ admits such a representation. Then show you can always exclude one of the numbers so the product isn't of the form $4k+2$.

Comment: The problem statement may be a bit ambiguous: Unless $0$ is a natural number, we need that the given natural numbers are *distinct* (or perhaps only that at least two of them are $\ne1$)

Comment: @J.G. That can be proved by looking at congruencies of squares modulo $4$. I assume we then just look at cases of the product of the $2022$ original numbers and its' remainder modulo $4$?

Comment: @Cookie Then again, you can also work with $(a+b)(a-b)$, which is an arbitrary product of two factors that are distinct but of same parity. In particular, it could be $m\cdot 1$ for odd $m\ge 3$, or it could be $\frac m2\cdot 2$ if $m>4$ is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: That's very interesting, I assume that's the solution here. Thanks. @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: Just one question, don't you mean if $m > 4$ is a multiple of $2$? @HagenvonEitzen